# why my array isn't working correctly [Google Map Api V3 ]

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

so i'm trying to do is when user click on the marker and  it will link user to the particular URL, but there's something wrong with it, it only link to the last array URL. may i know why ?

```
 for (var key in places){
            var myPlace = places[key];
            if (myPlace) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    url:myPlace.infowin_html,
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(myPlace.position.lat, myPlace.position.lng)
                });
                createTooltip(marker, key); 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.location.href=marker.url;
            }); 


        }


    }
```

my js

```
var places =Array();
places.push({
infowin_html:"https:www.facebook.com",
tooltip_html:"<div><img       src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/76/Habs_flw_oak_park_home.jpg/220px-Habs_flw_oak_park_home.jpg' width='220' hieght='174' /></div><h3>Chow Kit, KL</h3><div><stong>Population:</strong> 52k</div>Click for more..", 
position:{lat:3.1597, lng:101.7000}
});

places.push({
infowin_html:"https:www.facebook.com",
tooltip_html:"<h3>Subang Jaya, Selangor</h3><div><stong>Population:</strong> 2.7m</div>Click for more..",
position:{lat:3.0394, lng:101.5878}
});

places.push({
infowin_html:"https:www.facebook.com",
tooltip_html:"<h3>Puchong Jaya, Selangor</h3><div><stong>Population:</strong> 74k</div>Click for more..",
position:{lat:3.0113, lng:101.6115}
});

places.push({
infowin_html:"asd",
tooltip_html:"<h3>Cyberjaya, Selangor</h3><div><stong>Population:</strong>   55k</div>Click for more..",
position:{lat:2.9225, lng:101.6550}
});
```

what i get is "asd" URL .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is anonymous functions. You don't have any. That means, in marker is the last value of the loop. Which is ASD. So you need something like this, this way marker is not overwritten each time you loop, and will keep the value inside your handler.

```
for (var key in places){
   (function(myPlace){
        if (myPlace) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                url:myPlace.infowin_html,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(myPlace.position.lat, myPlace.position.lng)
            });
            createTooltip(marker, key); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                window.location.href=marker.url;
            }); 
        }
    })(places[key]);
 }
```

Comment: Thank your very much ! i hope i can vote up your answer , but sadly i can't !